# Twilio StudioFlow ngrok 404

Tags: python, http, flask, twilio, ngrok

Hey guys I'm having a really strange issue with ngrok and Twilio StudioFlow.

For some reason, the ngrok setup using (type "ngrok http 5000" in command line) and then copy and pasting the link into StudioFlow http widgets has **stopped working**, when it was working fine earlier. Now, when the widgets are reached in the flow, I get these:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2021 02:18:10] "POST /reminders HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2021 02:18:10] "POST /week2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The flask routes are right (`/reminders and /week2`) and I am pasting them like so in the widgets (http://8b5dba64ef0c.ngrok.io/reminders) so I am really not sure why this is happening all of a sudden. Why can't twilio find my ngrok tunnel?

For context, I've tried running the flask app on different ports, but that doesn't solve the issue either. That leads me to believe theres something wrong with how to link is being read in to either twilio or my app. I haven't been able to find one though. An example of my code:

```
@app.route('/reminders', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def remmy():
    # Start our empty response
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        number = request.form['To']
        print(type(number))
        part = Part.query.filter_by(phone_num=number).first()

    def base_reminder(num):

        rem = '[#####]: Don\'t forget to complete your baseline survey to receive an incentive of $35.'
        message = client.messages.create(from_='+1###########',
                                         to=num,
                                         body=rem)
        resp = MessagingResponse()
        msg = resp.message
        return str(resp)

    if not part.baseline:
        base_reminder(part.phone_num)

    return str(resp)
```

Comment: What happens when you experiment with a tool like https://www.postman.com/ against those routes?

Comment: I have not tried postman but ngrok's inspect page returns this: `!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>`  What can postman do to help resolve this as I am unfamiliar with it?

Comment: Just tried postman, and it gives the same 404 error message.

Comment: Can you put a bare bones Flask Python config together and see if that works?

Comment: @Alan to be honest, I'm not sure how I would go about doing that Alan. Can you give an example please?

Comment: This may be a good one to try - https://github.com/twilio/starter-python

Comment: @Alan Thanks Alan once again. I've solved the issue which really was a commented out line lol. It was messing with how my app loaded up, created the app before declaring any routes. No clue how I missed it but thanks for the help!